# Using a plugin on a field which is the basis of a condition

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using the Selectric plugin on my project and I seem to be having an issue with fields which are the basis of a condition. I will try to explain this as best I can.

As an example I have this "Reason for contact" field:

[image: Dropdown]

I have 2 options in this list simply being "Option 1" & "Option 2".

**I've set up a condition on the following fields**:

[image: Options]

**And this is the condition**:
[image]

So quite simply when the selected option doesn't match the field I want to show, it won't show. Now this rule works fine when the plugin isn't used. but when the plugin is used the condition doesn't trigger when then field is changed, it's worth noting that the fields validation updates just fine everytime the field is changed.

My question I guess is, is it possible to use a plugin with a field that powers a condition? If so, How can I tap into the condition to check it alongside the plugin?

Thanks in advance, and feel free to ask any questions below for more clarifation, I will get back as soon as possible!

Comment: Looks like the issue is that selected attribute is not adding to the option during onchange event

Comment: It's strange though, when I don't use the plugin, I can see it working fine, but I can't see any DOM updates onchange to tap into